# Issue while setting Window Size of Multi-Instance app with a Custom Titlebar

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, titlebar

I'm working on a UWP application that I want to launch at a specific compact size with a custom titlebar. This is working fine but I have an issue with the window size when I launch an additional instance or window of the app.

The second instance/window of the app's MainPage is taller by about 33 pixels or the exact height of the default title bar. The custom title bar is working correctly in the second window and I can manually resize that window so that it is the correct size.

[image]
Left window is the correct size and the right windows height is off by about 33 pixels.

The application is set up so that I can launch multiple instances. It does this using ApplicationViewSwitcher but I'm still unraveling if this could be the cause of the issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/application-view

Here's what I have for implementing a custom title bar and setting the window size at launch:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
        coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
        Window.Current.SetTitleBar(MyTitleBar);

        //Sets Window Size at open
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(new Size { Width = 350, Height = 127 });
        ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size(350, 127);
        ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
    }
```

Any ideas as to what could be causing the issue?

My current solution is to try to resize the window after UI elements are loaded. This works but its far from ideal and you can see the unsightly adjustment to window size:

```
 private async void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Delay(300);

        var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
        if (view.TryResizeView(new Size { Width = 350, Height = 127 }))
    }
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. Do you mean when you set the main window as 350, 127, it displayed well, but when launched a second window, the second window was 33 pixels taller than the main view? Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Comment: Hey! Sorry for any confusion. Yes that's exactly the issue. Here's a simple sample that demonstrates the issue: https://github.com/jjouppi/SecondWindowIssue
After building the app, launch a second instance of the application and you should see that the second window is taller then the original. I believe it has something to do with how WIndowManagerService.cs launches the second window using ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync. There is a view size property for ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync but any changes I have not had any effect.

Comment: To resize the second view, it's better to use TryResizeView method. You could try to add the TryResizeView method after TryShowAsStandaloneAsync() method instead of in Grid_Loaded event.